# iOS integration SDK, package

Tags: ios, xcode

I have integrated an SDK in my app. Why is the SDK appearing under the app when it is packaged?

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

because this sdk contain a framework . if you can compile it and update to itunesconnect successful . You don't have to care about it.